# How can I return only the digits from a large string with symbols, letters and of course digits with C#

Tags: c#, regex, digits

I have this code down here and I need to return the **args.Content** (my input data) with only digits and deleteing the rest of characteres. I've been trying many things with regular expressions but it didnt work for me. I have almost no idea of C# and I really need the help from the programers of this website.

```
using System;
using VisualWebRipper.Internal.SimpleHtmlParser;
using VisualWebRipper;
public class Script
{

    public static string TransformContent(WrContentTransformationArguments args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Place your transformation code here.
            //This example just returns the input data
            return args.Content;
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            //Place error handling here
            args.WriteDebug("Custom script error: " + exp.Message);
            return "Custom script error";
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just delete anything that is not a digit. There is a predefined character class for digits: `\d`, the negation is `\D`.

So you regex is simply:

```
\D+
```

In your C# code it would be something like

```
return Regex.Replace(args.Content, @"\D+", "");
```

Comment: Oh great, many thanks...now I need to separate this number between ";" every 8 numbers. The args.content now returns to me 16 digits  like this "0123456789012345" and I need to get something like this : "01234567;89012345" So many thanks again ^^

Comment: Is the `;` in the original string or do you want to insert it afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly not the most efficient, but oh, well, I couldn't resist doing some LINQ:

```
var digitsOnly = new string(args.Content.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
```

Comment: +1: I now shall delete my own _identical_ answer. This isn't a job for Regex IMHO

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{1}");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(args.Content);
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    builder.Append(match.ToString());
}
return builder.ToString();
```